# Using style from a NextJS module CSS stylesheet

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I have a stylesheet for a button which is located at `styles/Button.module.css` and i am trying to use it in my NextJS project but can't seem to get it going.

In my component, i have imported the stylesheet normally, i.e;

```
import Button from '../styles/Button.module.css';
```

Then i am trying to add it to the return in a component, like so;

```
<button onClick={e => login(e)} className={"text-white bg-indigo-600 " + (loading ? "Button.btn-loading" : "")}>
    Login
</button>
```

But the styles don't seem to be pulling through.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Button.btn-loading" is invalid. Button is an imported JS object, hence you need to remove the quotes to evaluate the JS object notation.

```
<button onClick={e => login(e)} className={"text-white bg-indigo-600 " + (loading ? Button['btn-loading'] : "")}>
    Login
</button>
```

That's why CSS Modules recommends using camelCase class names, so that we can use dot notation instead of bracket notation to get the values.

I'd suggest using template literals for more cleaner syntax

```
<button onClick={e => login(e)} className={`text-white bg-indigo-600 ${loading ? Button['btn-loading']: ""}`}>
    Login
</button>
```

Comment: Hey, I am getting a `btn is not defined` error now

Comment: I manged to sort that error out by putting quotes around the class, like `'btn-loading'` ... Thank you for your help!

Comment: Oh you're right, you need quotes inside a bracket notation. I've edited the answer. Thanks to you too!